# REST in Parse $in to ObjectID of Pointer Error Code 106

Tags: javascript, rest, parse-platform

I'm trying to get the following query:

```
https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Video?where=
{"course":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Course","objectId":{"$in":["id1","id2"]}}}
```

I'm querying on Video table, on "course" field (It's a pointer) to get all videos that its course is one of ids passed in the array (For this reason I use $in) because if I don't use $in, I don't have problems but I don't need it.

The error is this:

```
{ 
   code: 106,
   error: "key objectId should be a string"
}
```

What I have to do? Do you have any idea??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with the `"$inQuery"`

```
where={"course":{"$inQuery":{"where":{"objectId":{"$in":["id1","id2"]}},"className":"Course"}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've not used the rest API, but the [guide](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#queries-compound-queries) indicates that you can compound conditions with $or, as follows...

```
https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Video?where={"$or":[
    {"course":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Course","objectId":"id1"}},
    {"course":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Course","objectId":"id2"}}
]}
```

Comment: @dahn it's working! but I need to use $in because I have an array where are all ids... I've tried to use the same sintaxys than you but $in instead of $or and it doesn't work...