# Parse Push Notifications to multiple users through REST API

Tags: json, parse-platform, push-notification

I'm sending push notifications from a rails app through the parse.com REST API.
Targeting a single user works great but targeting more users with `$in` doesn't seem to work in my scenario.

Here's my JSON Code:

```
{
    "where":
    {
        "user":
        {
            "__type":"Pointer",
            "className":"_User",
            "objectId":
            {
                "$in":["AAA","BBB","CCC"]
            }
        }
    },
    "data":
    { ...
```

Isn't it possible to use `$in` when targeting multiple users? I noticed that I'm also not able to to so in the parse.com push backend.

The response is:

```
{
    "code": 106,
    "error": "key objectId should be a string"
}
```

Anyone got an idea? I don't want to make an separate REST Call for every notification.

Comment: I found a similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30112465/rest-in-parse-in-to-objectid-of-pointer-error-code-106 but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, sorry I found the answer here: [REST in Parse $in to ObjectID of Pointer Error Code 106](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30112465/rest-in-parse-in-to-objectid-of-pointer-error-code-106)

Or in short, this code works:

```
{
    "where":
    {
        "user":
        {
            "$inQuery":
            {
                "where": {
                    "objectId":
                    {
                        "$in":["AAA","BBB","CCC"]
                    }
                },
                "className":"_User"
            }
        }
    },
    "data":
```